# Does every prime number split completely in number fields of arbitrarily large degree?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number.

Is there a sequence $(K_n)$ of number fields such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}[K_n:\mathbb{Q}]=\infty$ and $p$ splits completely in each $\mathcal{O}_{K_n}$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pick integers $a_1$, $\ldots$, $a_n$ independent modulo squares with $(a_j/p) = +1$ and consider the sequence of fields $K_n=  {\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{a_1}, \ldots, \sqrt{a_n})$.

Comment: Hm. Now I am confused. :)

Comment: What does indepenent modulo squares mean?

Comment: There should not be a relation of the form $\prod a_j = m^2$, otherwise the degree is not $2^n$.

Answer (score 4):

Somewhat to my surprise, it seems that I can more-or-less prove that this is not possible, basically because polynomials in $\mathbb F_p[x]$ that have all their roots in $\mathbb F_p$ must have *repeated* roots for degree $>p$.

Namely, suppose for a moment that the ring of integers $\mathfrak o$ of a field extension $k$ of $\mathbb Q$ is of the form $\mathfrak o=\mathbb Z[\theta]$, and let $P$ be the irreducible monic for $\theta$ over $\mathbb Q$. The splitting (etc) of $p$ is completely described by the factoring of $P$ in $\mathbb F_p[x]$: if $P=\prod_{i=1}^\ell P_i^{e_i}$, then there are $\ell$ primes lying over $p$, with residue class extension degrees $\deg P_i$, and ramification degrees $e^i$. Thus, for $p$ to split completely, the degrees of the $P_i$ must be $1$ (and they are distinct...), and the exponents $e_i$ must be $1$. Thus, the degree of $P$ can be at most $p$.

The assumption $\mathfrak o=\mathbb Z[\theta]$ can be weakened to the corresponding assumption for the localization of $\mathbb Z$ "at" $p$, where denominators prime to $p$ are allowed. Here is the possible gap in my argument: I *think* that it is "well-known" that finite integral extensions of Dedekind rings with finitely-many primes are monogenic... but at the moment I cannot recall the presumably not-so-hard proof.

Comment: Thank you. What about just taking $\ell$ to infinity without worrying about the residue class extension degrees? Can we find a sequence of number fields that takes $\ell$ to infinity for our fixed prime number $p$? Maybe some cyclotomic fields can work? (this probably involves worrying about the residue class extenstion degrees a little bit, just to show that they grow in a sublinear rate with respect to the degree of the cyclotoic extension. Is this true for some sequence of cyclotomic extensions?)

Comment: Yes, I'd be confident that (via Dirichlet's theorem about primes in arithmetic progressions) we could make a sequence of cyclotomic fields in which a given prime splits into more-and-more primes.

Comment: About the monogenicity issue: there are DVRs with an integral closure in a finite extension which is not even module-finite, let along monogenic.

Comment: @LukasHeger, hm!!! Are such examples "easy", or "natural"? I have no idea...

Comment: @paulgarrett no, they are quite pathological and can only exists due inseparability (which is why they're not really relevant here, but I mentioned it as a caution about general claims regarding monogenecity)

Comment: irrc one can construct an example as follows: Let $k=\Bbb F_p(T_1, T_2, \ldots)$ and let $K=\Bbb F_P(\sqrt[p]{T_1}, \sqrt{p}{T_2}, \ldots)$. Now let $R$ be the subring of $K[[X]]$ consiting of those power series whose coefficients generate a finite extension of $k$. I have never looked deeply into this example, so I don't know exactly why this is a DVR. But if you take any element of $a\in K[[X]] \setminus R$, then $R[a]$ does not have a module-finite integral closure in its field of fractions.

Comment: @LukasHeger, hm! Thanks!

Comment: But, now, @franzlemmermeyer's example, which is completely unsurprising from some viewpoint, together with this Dedekind factorization argument, has some peculiar implications... ?!?

Comment: i believe both answers :-/   all of @franzlemmermeyer's quadratic extensions are going to be monogenic at $p \neq 2$, no?

Comment: This answer only shows that any example cannot be (locally) monogenic. In particular it shows that franzlemmermeyer's example is not (locally) monogenic